# The Developing Map

Tags: reference-request, manifolds, low-dimensional-topology

I am looking for resources to learn about the developing map, but the only source I know is Thurston's book. Could anyone direct me to other sources? Lecture notes, articles, books, etc?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at the sources cited here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/139410/question-about-the-developing-map?

Comment: take a look [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.20.7118&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4381723/169085